# POST returns a 415. REST webapp in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

This is the post method...

```
   @POST
   @Consumes("application/xml")
   public Response createCustomer(Customer customer) {
      customer.setId(idCounter.incrementAndGet());
      customerDB.put(customer.getId(), customer);
      System.out.println("Created customer " + customer.getId());
      return Response.created(URI.create("/customers/" + customer.getId())).build();
   }
```

I am not getting any logs to view in Netbeans or the server (Glassfish).

This is what I am sending..

```
<customer><first-name>Bill</first-name><last-name>Burke</last-name><street>256 Clarendon Street</street><city>Boston</city><state>MA</state><zip>02115</zip><country>USA</country></customer>
```

What is causing the 415? Im confused.

[image]

Picture of the application class...

[image]

Picture of the customer
[image]

I can confirm, also, that `System.out.println("Customer Resource is created.");` get printed.

Also, here is the web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

Comment: What is your content type header in the headers tab?

Comment: Content-Type: "application/xml"

Comment: Is that 100% the right URL?

Comment: yes. ill post pics of the code...

Comment: added images and the web.xml @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Please replace them with text as its much easier to copy paste etc. - thank you

Comment: ill make it more simple. I am using https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/restful-java-with/9780596809300/ch03.html as a reference. @ErmiyaEskandary